# Appending params to object[]

Tags: java, arrays, append

I have the following parms.

```
     Object[] params = new Object[] { request.getInsuranceId(), request.getSrcSysCd};
```

How can i append more params to Object[] params based on certain conditions. For eg

```
if(StringUtils.hasText(request.getGroupId()){ append param request.getGroupId}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append an **Array** in Java because their space in memory is already fixed, but you could instead use an **ArrayList**.

```
Object[] obj = new Object[] { obj1 , obj2, obj3 };
ArrayList<Object> newObj = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(obj));
newObj.add("new value");
newObj.add("new value 2");
```